# How to prevent QSystemTrayIcon's contextMenu from hiding when clicked?

Tags: qt, qsystemtrayicon

I'm trying to enable users to click on an action in a `QSystemTrayIcon`'s `contextMenu` multiple times without making it hide, which happens by default.

I tried to `show` the `contextMenu` when an action is triggered (clicked), so it makes it show up after hiding, but the problem with this is that the `contextMenu` will pop up at the top left corner of the screen, because it takes a `QPoint(0,0)` I'm guessing, and it does not have the my system's theme as well. Below is what I mean:

normal `ContextMenu`:

[image: Normal]

`ContextMenu` that pops up at the top left corner when using `show`:

[image: Not Normal]

I also tried to emit `activated` signal with `QSystemTrayIcon::Context`, but that did nothing, although `QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger` works perfectly.

I'm using:

- KDE Neon
- X11
- Qt 6.5.0